# Variables with function calls as dependencies in GNU Make

Tags: gnu-make

Is it possible to use generated variables as dependencies inside a GNU Make rule? I am trying to do

```
A := 1 2 3
B := a b c
C := $(foreach X,$(A),$(foreach Y,$(B),$X-$Y))

a:
    echo A

b:
    echo B

$(C) : $(word 2,$(subst -, ,$@))
    echo $@
```

I would like to be able to run

```
make 2-a
```

and get `echo A` and `echo $@`, that is, I want `$(word 2,$(subst -, ,$@))` to be evaluated as dependency list. However, it seems like it is evaluated before the rules are matched.

Is it possible, without an external program, to have variables with function calls as dependencies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gods of GNUmake foresaw your desires and implemented `.SECONDEXPANSION`:

```
A := 1 2 3
B := a b c
C := $(foreach X,$(A),$(foreach Y,$(B),$X-$Y))

a:
    echo A

b:
    echoechoecho B

.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(C) : $$(word 2,$$(subst -, ,$$@))
    echo $@
```

All rules which appear after this label will be subject to a second expansion of their prerequisite list, which means that you can use automatic variables like `$@`which are undefined during the first expansion.
All you have to take into consideration is that you need to quote every `$` (i.e. make it a `$$`) that shall spring into effect only during the second expansion of the prerequisite list.